# How to transpose/pivot one column into row flipping all the row information after it?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have weather station data that I have imported with read_csv in RStudio. It's messy, my main concern is the column called "item" which contains variables for weather readings. This needs to be a row/header, with all the time series data also flipped under it, since this is data specific to each variable, and in time order.

You may also notice the header/first row starting at 00 contains the time information and I will also have to deal with this. For now I just want to pivot/transpose the variable names with all their data.

Here's the initial data, included as tibble and example data below (weatherstation). The dataframe has many more rows and columns go to '23', it's hourly data for each day for a month. The time/hour data is conveniently the column headers (sarcastic)

```
A tibble: 6 × 10
##   date       station item      `00`  `01`  `02`  `03` `04`   `05`  `06`
##   <date>     <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2015-01-01 Cailiao AMB_TEMP 16     16   15    15    15    14    14   
## 2 2015-01-01 Cailiao CO        0.74   0.7  0.66  0.61 0.51   0.51  0.51
## 3 2015-01-01 Cailiao NO        1      0.8  1.1   1.7  2      1.7   1.9 
## 4 2015-01-01 Cailiao NO2      15     13   13    12    11    13    13   
## 5 2015-01-01 Cailiao NOx      16     14   14    13    13    15    15   
## 6 2015-01-01 Cailiao O3       35     36   35    34    34    32    30

structure(list(date = structure(c(16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
16436, 16436), class = "Date"), station = c("Cailiao",         "Cailiao", 
"Cailiao", "Cailiao", "Cailiao", "Cailiao"), item =  c("AMB_TEMP", 
"CO", "NO", "NO2", "NOx", "O3"), `00` = c(16, 0.74, 1, 15, 16, 
35), `01` = c(16, 0.7, 0.8, 13, 14, 36), `02` = c(15, 0.66, 1.1, 
13, 14, 35), `03` = c(15, 0.61, 1.7, 12, 13, 34), `04` = c("15", 
"0.51", "2", "11", "13", "34"), `05` = c(14, 0.51, 1.7, 13, 15, 
32), `06` = c(14, 0.51, 1.9, 13, 15, 30), `07` = c(14, 0.6, 2.4, 
16, 18, 26), `08` = c("14", "0.62", "3.4", "16", "19", "26"), 
`09` = c("15", "0.58", "3.7", "14", "18", "29"), `10` = c("14", 
"0.53", "3.5", "12", "15", "33"), `11` = c("15", "0.49", 
"3.4", "11", "15", "38"), `12` = c("15", "0.45", "3.3", "11", 
"14", "38"), `13` = c("15", "0.4", "3.1", "9.8", "13", "40"
 ), `14` = c("14", "0.4", "3.2", "11", "14", "39"), `15` =  c("13", 
"0.41", "2.5", "11", "14", "35"), `16` = c("13", "0.44", 
"2.9", "14", "17", "31"), `17` = c("13", "0.45", "2.2", "15", 
"17", "30"), `18` = c("12", "0.41", "2.3", "16", "18", "30"
), `19` = c(13, 0.42, 2.3, 18, 20, 27), `20` = c("13", "0.31", 
"1.8", "13", "15", "30"), `21` = c(13, 0.3, 1.9, 13, 15, 
28), `22` = c(13, 0.32, 2.1, 14, 16, 27), `23` = c(13, 0.33, 
1.8, 16, 17, 25)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
## # A tibble: 6 × 10
##   date       station hour   AMB_TEMP    CO    NO   NO2   NOx    O3  PM10
##   <date>     <chr>   <time>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2015-01-01 Cailiao 00:00        16  0.74   1      15    16    35   171
## 2 2015-01-01 Cailiao 01:00        16  0.7    0.8    13    14    36   174
## 3 2015-01-01 Cailiao 02:00        15  0.66   1.1    13    14    35   160
## 4 2015-01-01 Cailiao 03:00        15  0.61   1.7    12    13    34   142
## 5 2015-01-01 Cailiao 04:00        15  0.51   2      11    13    34   123
## 6 2015-01-01 Cailiao 05:00        14  0.51   1.7    13    15    32   110
```

I've tried both pivot_wider and pivot_longer in various combinations with no luck. Here's a few examples of my attempts (I'm new to data tidying so there may be errors). I feel like there must be some function to help with this that I don't know about or a variation of something I've tried that I can't figure out on my own. I was hoping pivot would solve my problem but it seems to have trouble reading 'item' (maybe I need to give it more info but not sure what)

```
weather2 <- weatherstation %>% pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value)

weather2 <- weatherstation %>% pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = 00:23)

t_weatherstation <- t(weatherstation)
```

Next I tried transposing (t(weatherstationcsv)) which has worked best but introduces other issues (below) like spreading out each variable (amb_temp etc) into duplicate columns for each hour entry and truncating the hourly entries vertically

```
## # A tibble: 6 × 10
##   item  amb_temp co       no       no2      n_ox     o3            pm10  pm2_5 rainf…¹
##   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  
## 1 00    " 16.00" "  0.74" "  1.00" " 15.00" " 16.00" " 35.0…  171.… " 76… <NA>   
## 2 01    " 16.00" "  0.70" "  0.80" " 13.00" " 14.00" " 36.0… 174.… " 78… <NA>   
## 3 02    " 15.00" "  0.66" "  1.10" " 13.00" " 14.00" " 35.0… 160.… " 69… <NA>   
## 4 03    " 15.00" "  0.61" "  1.70" " 12.00" " 13.00" " 34.0… 142.… " 60… <NA>   
## 5 04    "15"     "0.51"   "2"      "11"     "13"     "34"    123   "52"  NR     
## 6 05    " 14.00" "  0.51" "  1.70" " 13.00" " 15.00" " 32.0…  110.… " 44… <NA>
```

I was thinking of separating/removing date and station altogether to deal with the rest of the mess.

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you can share example data as code instead of its printed appearance. I'd suggest running `dput(head(weatherstation))` and pasting the output of that into the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll add that now!

Comment: You need to ``pivot_longer(`00`:`06`)`` and then  `pivot_wider(names_from = item)`

Comment: Thank you Darren, that's exactly what worked. I was resistant to pivoting the time first but its exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
weatherstation %>%
  mutate(across(`00`:`23`, as.numeric)) %>%   # some columns numeric, some char
  pivot_longer(-c(1:3), names_to = "hour") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value)
```

...but I'm not sure what sort of `<time>` class you want for the hours

Comment: Thank you Jon, that worked perfectly! I didn't even think of trying to pivot the hours longer. I'm not sure about the time class at the moment but I think I'll be able to change it if needed! I was struggling so much just to get those columns tidy'ed, I can't thank you enough.